# I'm having trouble getting SVP 4 Linux to run

Tags: 16.04, dependencies

I just installed SVP with all the prerequisites beforehand. When I try to launch it, though, its icon appears in the Unity launcher for a few seconds, then just disappears without the program even opening. I've already tried running

```
ldd SVPManager
```

as https://www.svp-team.com/wiki/SVP:Linux recommends, but all the terminal returns is

```
ldd: ./SVPManager: No such file or directory
```